# Did Perry Mason ever lose a case?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, perry-mason-1957

Did Perry Mason ever lose a case and if he did how many cases did he actually lose?

Comment: In the books or in th movies?

Comment: Movies @Vishwa is what I meant

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, Mason did lose, more than once according to the some sources I found.

**From [funtrivia](http://www.funtrivia.com/askft/Question42496.html), forum,** one person states that,

> Mason actually lost two murder cases in the original series. But in
>   one, "The Case of the Terrified Typist," he was misled by his client,
>   and in the other, "The Case of the Deadly Verdict," his client was
>   eventually cleared.

Another person states that,

> Mason is known to have lost, in some form or manner, three cases-"The
>   Case of the Terrified Typist", "The Case of the Witless Witness", and
>   "The Case of the Deadly Verdict".
>
> Mason also loses a civil case at the beginning of "The Case of the
>   Dead Ringer", partly due to being framed for witness tampering.

**Read more on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perry_Mason_(TV_series))**

In NPR, states that Mason lost only one case though. Interview with Barbara Hale, who played Della Street in the long-running TV show, talks about Perry Mason's loss.

**Read the article [here](https://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=106666458)**

perrymasontvshowbook.com states that Mason lost three cases.

Read the article [here](http://www.perrymasontvshowbook.com/pmb_c209.htm)

Comment: You forgot his technical loss on his appearance on the flintsones

Comment: @AbrahamRay uh..what?

Comment: Perry mason had a cameo on the Flintstones @Vishwa

Comment: in the real movie or animated series of the porn parody thing? ;)

Comment: Animated cartoon @vishwa